# Passing Client-side JavaScript Param to Server-side JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Guys I've search for a solution for this problem with no luck, wish if someone could help.

I'm building nodejs express app, in one of .ejs I'm trying to compare mongoDB Id of the selected item with the id passed in the query string in order to change the selected item accordingly.

Below is the code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
              <tr>
                  <th>Available Models</th>
              </tr>
              <script>
                <% var index = 0; %>
              </script>
              <% if(modelId) { %>
              <script>
                for(i =0; i <= document.getElementById("mnumake").options.length;i++) {
                  var optionValue = document.getElementById("mnumake").options[i].value;
                  if (<% modelId.equals(%> optionValue <% ) %> ) {
                  index = i;
                  document.getElementById("mnumake").options[i].selected = true;
                  break
                  }
                } 
              </script>
              <%  }  %>
              <% makes[index].models.forEach(function(model){ %>
                  <tr><td><%= model.name %></td></tr>
              <% }) %>
        </table>
```